# How to tell astyle to do nothing?

Tags: c, formatting, coding-style, astyle

I want to apply only one formatting rule from pletora of astyle capabilities - and nothing else.

However, I find it impossible to turn off all astyle options - no matter what, I end up with aweful lot of undesired formatting changes.

How to tell astyle to apply just a single formatting rule? Or, to apply no formatting rule, after which I would just enable my single desired rule?